# Connect Objectify caching with Google Cloud MemoryStore

Tags: objectify, app-engine-flexible, google-cloud-memorystore

I try to implement Objectify's MemcacheService to run with Google Cloud MemoryStore.

I managed to implement the basic methods like put and get, but I have no idea how to implement

`Set<String> putIfUntouched(final Map<String, CasPut> values);`

and

`Map<String, IdentifiableValue> getIdentifiables(final Collection<String> keys);`

I do not find a way to get the necessary Cas infos from MemoryStore.

I already tried to connect Objectify with a running memcached instance, but I feel I do not have as much control as I would with the MemoryStore (in terms of monitoring, flushing etc.).

Any tips on how to implement the MemcacheService are very much appreciated.

Comment: I am by no means a redis expert, but this looks like the critical api: https://redis.io/topics/transactions#cas

Comment: Hi @stickfigure, thanks for pointing in that direction. After having a closer look, transactions in Jedis work totally different from how memcached uses the CAS infos. There is no way to keep the CAS info from the first get of a key until the put in putIfUntouched().

Comment: What is the worst case scenario, if we just drop the CAS info and put the object to memcache in any case?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can implement the cache CAS operations using Redis primitives. Ultimately it's a matter of changing a version value attached to an entry on every write. When you getIdentifiable you also fetch the version, and when you putIfUntouched you submit the version too and check it against the stored data. This is what memcache does.

Comment: Dropping the CAS behavior would allow race conditions under contention that leave stale data in your cache. This isn't necessarily as bad as it sounds depending on your data consistency requirements - if you put a reasonable expiration on the cache data, and you're ok with a worst-case-staleness of that expiration period, then it will be fine. But you probably want to be selective about which entities you are willing to treat that way.